# Event or callback when element is rendered by the browser

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

I have a table with multiple cells and one input element. Input element sits in one of the cells. By pressing tab key I'm moving input from one cell to another. At the end of this action I need to set focus to the input.

In chrome browser everything works fine. in IE everything works fine except for the last part (focus). It looks like due to slower rendering in IE at the time I'm setting the focus the input element not rendered yet.

```
function goNext(){
  var input = $('input');
  var td = input.parent();
  var all = $('table td');
  for(var i = 0; i < all.length; i++){
    if (td[0] === all[i]){
        if (i === 3){
          all[0].appendChild(input[0]);
        } else {
          all[i+1].appendChild(input[0]);
        }
    }
  }  
  input.focus();  
}
```

If I wrap input.focus into setTimeout with 100 milliseconds it works fine, but I don't think that's a right approach.

Is there any way to know when rendering is completed? I've tried MutationObserver, but it doesn't work for whole table and I don't want to observe each cell. Here is [demo](https://jsbin.com/yewukokoka/1/edit?html,js,output) that illustrates the issue.

Comment: You can use the `MutationObserver` to check on all the children of the table. Check the [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/nl/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver#MutationObserverInit) and look for `childList`.

Comment: Like I said I've tried that, but it doesn't work for whole table and I don't want to observe each cell since table can be really big.

Comment: Probably because you are moving the input field around. How about using 4 input fields, having only one ever visible at a time?

Comment: why are you mixing jQuery and DOM?

Comment: No need to be wasteful, a single input that gets moved around is fine. JS is single-threaded, though, so there is literally no guarantee that `appendChild` actually runs when you tell it to. The fact that it works in Chrome is really more of an accident than anything: you can't rely on it. While timeout/requestanimationframe _might_ work, the only guaranteed signal that you can _rely_ on is a subtree mutation, which you can listen for with a [mutation observer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver/observe#Example)

Answer (score 0):

Please try to use the following code:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="text" class="txtbox" /></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
</table>
<script>
    $(function () {
        $(".txtbox")[0].focus();
        //clone the textbox 
        var itemtemp = $(".txtbox")[0].outerHTML;
        //current focus textbox number.
        var currentactive = 0;

        $('table').keydown(function (e) {
            if (e.keyCode === 9) {
                console.log('tab pressed');
                AddTextBox();
                goNext();
                e.preventDefault();
                e.stopPropagation();
            }
        });

        //focus to next texbox 
        function goNext() {
            var input = $('.txtbox');
            currentactive++;
            input[currentactive].focus();
            if (currentactive ==3) {
                currentactive = -1;
            }
        }

        var tdcount = $('table td').length;
        //add textbox 
        function AddTextBox() {
            if (currentactive < tdcount && $("table td")[currentactive + 1].innerHTML == "") {
                console.log("add new textbox");
                $("table td")[currentactive + 1].innerHTML = itemtemp;
            }
        }
    })
</script>
```

The result as below (using IE 11 browser, after clicking the Tab key, it will add a new textbox and set focus on it):

[image]

Comment: Zhi Lv - MSFT, Thank you for your solution. It works fine except that I need to have just one text box and if try to clear currentactive cell in AddTextBox() after new textbox is created the focus is getting lost.